# How do I change the name of a file?

Tags: windows, git, visual-studio, bitbucket

In visual studio 2015 I changed the name of a file in my project (from test.ps1 to test.psm1). I saved my project. I committed the file (this is a git bitbucket repo) and pushed.

The filename in VS changed, but it did not change in the file system. If I view it in explorer its still called test.ps1. If I view it in bitbucket its called "test.psm1"!

What the heck happened and how do I do this right?

Edit:
OK so now I have a problem where modifying a file in VS is not reflected in the file system. Maybe I'm just misunderstanding how VS works?

I create a file in my project, or edit an exiting file and save and I don't see any changes on the file system.

If I commit and push I see those changes in my commits in bitbucket, why don't I see them on the file system?

Whats crazy is if I create a new file in VS I don't see it in file explorer, BUT if I open a PS console and do "Get-Item fullPathOfFileICantSeeInExplorer.ps1" it finds it! What the hell is happening?

Comment: Per your edit, that is weird. When's the last reboot?

Answer (score 1):

Copy the problem file to another file system location and rename it.

Delete the problem file using Visual Studio from your project.

Add the renamed file to your file system location of where it was in your project.

Add existing file using Visual Studio and select the renamed file.

Finally, Commit.

Comment: Renaming is definitely funny business using Source Control and VS, especially on folders.

Comment: So now I have a problem where modifying a file in VS is not reflected in the file system. Maybe I'm just misunderstanding how VS works? I create a file in my project, or edit an exiting file and save and I don't see any changes on the file system. If I commit and push I see those changes in my commits in bitbucket, why don't I see them on the file system?

Comment: Probably not for file extensions as your file was. As I also mentioned, folders don't do this either. Essentially, VS is still pointing to that file but the name only changes in what you see in VS because I guess Microsoft assumes that you will only be working from VS and not have anything to do with your file system is my only guess. You may also try changing the file extension on your file system instead of through VS next time. After changing extension, right click on the project and "Reload" to see if that works around for you.

Comment: Also, you can always view the properties (F4) of any file to see the full path. Maybe the file moved somewhere.